# How to set Django constraints to allow one enabled (BooleanField) object per item?

Tags: python, django

How to set Django constraints (or `unique_together`) to allow one enabled object per item?

```
class Subscription(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    enabled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Should not allow to:

```
item1 = Item.objects.get(...)
sub1 = Subscription.objects.create(item=item1, enabled=True)
sub2 = Subscription.objects.create(item=item1, enabled=True)
```

but this should be allowed:

```
item1 = Item.objects.get(...)
sub1 = Subscription.objects.create(item=item1, enabled=True)
sub2 = Subscription.objects.create(item=item1, enabled=False)
```

Comment: I doubt this can be done with unique_together. How about put this condition in a save() method instead? e.g. whenever you enable one subscription it could automatically disable all other subscriptions. Would that work for you?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat so I should add something like that: `models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['item'], condition=Q(enabled=True), name='unique_enabled_per_company')` ?

Comment: @12735961238 yes, that would do what you want. Note: The forms won't validate this constraint automatically you would need to add some validation for that.